# Action Bar increased space between Title and Icon

Tags: android, android-actionbar-compat

I'm setting Action Bar for my app's ChatActivity but space between Icon and Title is so much that title is not visible

[image]

Here is my code

```
ab.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
ab.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
ab.setLogo(R.drawable.profile_default);
ab.setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(true);
ab.setTitle("Hello");
ab.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);
```

I dont know why there is much spacing between elements.
Please help me fix this.

edit 1:
Here is part of my activity layout xml:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/contacts_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />
```

Comment: can you share xml layout ?

Comment: well I have not set any menu xml file because I don't need it. I've added part of activity layout xml in edit 1.

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/relative1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/my_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/colorToolbar"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
        app:titleTextColor="#000000"
       >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="center">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/back"
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_keyboard_arrow_left_black_24dp" />


        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Your Title"
            android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:gravity="center"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/logout"
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginEnd="18dp"
            android:background="@drawable/logout"
            />
        </RelativeLayout>
```

Hope this is helpful.

Comment: Sorry but it is not helpful. It spoils native Action Bar experience. For example, ripple effect in this custom layout becomes rectangular insted of circular.

Comment: try this , https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45451119/react-native-action-bar-and-react-native-menu